# codeigniter set_userdata works but doesnt output set_flashdata, in the same code

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

I have a user controller that checks to login a user. It has this snippet of code. I can set set_userdata and echo it in my view, but this doesnt work for my flash data as shown below.

```
 public function login()
    {
        if($this->input->post('submit_login'))
        {
            // Get Posted Vars
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password  = md5($this->input->post('password'));

            // Run query to return 1 result if TRUE
            $query = $this->user_model->check_login($username, $password);

            if ($query == FALSE)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('flashdata', 'Incorrect Username or Password doesnt show');
                $this->session->set_userdata('userdata', 'userdata works');
                // Query was wrong, set flash data and redirect to login
                $data['main_content'] = "user/login";
                $data['title'] = "Login";
                $this->load->view('template', $data);
            }
            else // Else Query returned 1 item
            {
                // Get the Variables
                $user_id = $query->row(0)->id;
                $username = $query->row(0)->username;
                $user_email = $query->row(0)->email;
                $user_type = $query->row(0)->type;

                // Load up the userdata array
                $userdata = array(
                    'logged_in' => TRUE,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'user_email' => $user_email,
                    'user_type' => $user_type
                    );

                // Execute the set_userdata, to our session
                $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);

                $data['main_content'] = "Admin/index";
                $data['title'] = "Administrator";
                $this->load->view('template', $data);
            }
        }
        elseif ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
        {
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
                $data['main_content'] = "user/login";
                $data['title'] = "Login";
                $this->load->view('template', $data);
        }
```

Then in my view:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/login" method="POST" id="login_form"/>
<p>Please Login Below</p>
<span class="notice"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('flashdata'); ?></span>
<span class="label">Username:</span><input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
<span class="label">Password:</span><input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit_login" value="Login"/>
</form>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('flashdata'); ?>
<br/>
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('userdata'); ?>
```

Why doesnt flashdata show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flashdata` in codeigniter only exists in the session for one additional request and then is destroyed.  If you are inadvertently trying to use it past a single request, it will not exist by the time you try and access it.  `userdata` though exists as long as the session exists.

***UPDATE***

After looking at more of your code, it looks like this happens because you're not actually redirecting (creating the next request) here, you're just loading a view...

```
        if ($query == FALSE)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flashdata', 'Incorrect Username or Password doesnt show');
            $this->session->set_userdata('userdata', 'userdata works');
            // Query was wrong, set flash data and redirect to login
            $data['main_content'] = "user/login";
            $data['title'] = "Login";
            $this->load->view('template', $data);  //<---- See?
        }
```

Instead do this...

```
        if ($query == FALSE)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flashdata', 'Incorrect Username or Password doesnt show');
            $this->session->set_userdata('userdata', 'userdata works');
            // Query was wrong, set flash data and redirect to login
            redirect("uri/path/to/login");
        }
```

Comment: I understand that, but it doesnt show on the first request. I've added more code.

Comment: Thanks! that worked!, I understand, I was just loading a view which was the same request. but I have to redirect for the next request.

Answer (score 1):

The value of :

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('flashdata');
```

Will get on 2nd refresh of the page.

Actually, this value is stored in cookies.